# How to convert promise object to object in class

Tags: javascript, class, promise, async-await

i want to fetch data from outside of my project with axios. i do it in side of class but for some reason i retrieve data in promise object i use await and promise but eventually i receive data in [object promise].

```js
const Online_Visitors_System = class OnlineVisitors {
  constructor() {
    // get VisitorIP
    this.IP = this.fetchIP();
    // config redis for key space notification
    this.redis = Redis.createClient();
    this.redis.on("ready", () => {
      this.redis.config("SET", "notify-keyspace-events", "KEA");
    });
    PubSub.subscribe("__keyevent@0__:incrby");
  }
  async fetchIP() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return axios
        .get("https://api.ipgeolocation.io/getip")
        .then(res => resolve(res.data.ip));
    });
  }
  VisitorInter() {
    console.log(this.IP);
  }
};

module.exports = new Online_Visitors_System();
```

error that i encounter with it::

```
This is converted to "[object Promise]" by using .toString() now and will return an error from v.3.0 
on.
Please handle this in your code to make sure everything works as you intended it to.
Promise { '51.38.89.159' }
```

Comment: `this.IP.then(ip => console.log(ip));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you missed await in fews places, here is full correction:

```
const Online_Visitors_System = class OnlineVisitors{
    constructor(){
        // get VisitorIP
        this.fetchIP().then(ip => this.IP = ip);

        // config redis for key space notification
        this.redis = Redis.createClient();
        this.redis.on('ready',()=>{
            this.redis.config('SET',"notify-keyspace-events",'KEA')
        })
        PubSub.subscribe("__keyevent@0__:incrby")
    }
    fetchIP(){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            axios.get('https://api.ipgeolocation.io/getip')
            .then(res=>resolve(res.data.ip))     
        })
    }
 VisitorInter(){
     console.log(this.IP)
 }
};
```

Since the method `fetchIP` is an async function you need also `await` when calling it,
so: `this.IP = await this.fetchIP()`.
But since you are in construcot you can't use await so the solution is to use chaning:
`this.fetchIP().then(ip => this.IP = ip);`

Note that when initating new `Promise` you need to give it an `async` function, because inside that you are awating other methods.

Comment: You can't `await` in a non-async function and you can't make `constructor`s `async`.

Comment: Well true, i missed that, did not notice that this is a constructor

Comment: Please note that `this.IP` might be `undefined` by the time `VisitorInter()` is called with this implementation.

Comment: @SajjadHadafi thanks, But anyway the answer of AKX is better, so use that code instead of my.

Comment: @Dahou your answer clarified this issue well for me i used your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the *promise* of an IP address into `this.IP`.

You will need to `.then` the promise to get the actual IP address; it might or might not be available by the time `VisitorInter()` or anything else that needs the IP address is called.

```
class OnlineVisitors {
  constructor() {
    this.ipPromise = this.fetchIP();
    // redis stuff elided from example
  }
  async fetchIP() {
    const resp = await axios.get("https://api.ipgeolocation.io/getip");
    return resp.data.ip;
  }
  async VisitorInter() {
    const ip = await this.ipPromise;  // this could potentially hang forever if ipgeolocation.io doesn't feel like answering
    console.log(ip);
  }
};

module.exports = new OnlineVisitors();
```

Comment: you have a typo : const resp, but res.data